# XSS: terminology

Tags: web-application, xss

Where does the name XSS come from?
Why "cross-site"?
Also, the book "The Web Application Hacker's Handbook" says that the name XSS is a misnomer when talking about "stored XSS" or second-order XSS attacks. Why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is trivial to look up on Wikipedia. for a bit more information you can take a look at OWASP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding why it has cross-site in the name, [Jeremiah Grossman has a good article](http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2006/07/origins-of-cross-site-scripting-xss.html) on that.  Snipit below:

> What was soon discovered was that a malicious website could load
>   another website into an adjacent frame or window, then use JavaScript
>   to read into it. One website could cross a boundry and script into
>   another page. Pull data from forms, re-write the page, etc. Hence the
>   name cross-site scripting (CSS). Notice the use of "CSS". Netscape
>   fired back with the "same-origin policy", designed to prevent such
>   behavior. And the browser hackers took this as a challenge and began
>   finding what seems like hundreds of ways to circumvent the security.

Different from what we describe as XSS today, but that appears to be the origin.

I guess WAHH singles out stored XSS as being a misnomer because a reflected XSS attack could potentially originate from a malicious site which would make the name "cross-site-scripting" more accurate.  I would think that DOM based XSS would fall into the same category as stored XSS.

Without seeing exactly what they say about XSS it's hard to say why they are saying it.